# Terminology: any specific name for the amount of something in a given volume (at a given time)?

Tags: conservation-laws, terminology

For quantities such as electric charge, amount of substance (or number of particles), and energy, the *flux* of the quantity is defined as the amount of quantity flowing through a predefined surface in unit time (at least, [the term is consistently used this way in SI definitions](https://goldbook.iupac.org/indexes/quantities)).

I was wondering if you've ever heard of a term, analogous to "flux", for denoting the amount of quantity present in a predefined volume at a particular time. It's basically the volume integral of the *density* (like the flux is the surface integral of the *flux density*, according to the SI). I don't think I ever have.

The term *amount* doesn't quite work because too generic: it's also used in the definition of "flux", for example.

Such a term can become handy when speaking of conservation laws, which basically say $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\text{[missing word]} +\text{flux} = 0$$

(compare with $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\text{density} +\nabla\cdot\text{(flux density)} = 0$.)

Glad & thankful to anyone who can share references that discuss this, and anyone who can at least come up with a word that could be used for this.

**Edit**: I think I'll settle for *volume integral*, although it's a bit long; but at least it's less ambiguous than "amount" or "quantity". Still happy to hear about references or proposals though.

Comment: Concentration would be a good one: moles per volume. Density is another: mass per volume. Flux is slightly different in that it is related to a change of the amount of substance.

Comment: @MattHanson We have the pair "density"–"flux density" for that, yes. What's missing is a term which is to "density" what "flux" is to "flux density".

Comment: I think density is typically the term that joins up with flux, unless I am mistaken. See, for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation

Comment: @MattHanson there's surely a variety of uses! I think some writers indeed use "flux" for what the SI defines as "flux density". § A.6.3 of ISO 80000-1 says "The noun “density” or the adjective “areic” is added to the name of a quantity expressing a flux or a current to indicate the quotient of such a quantity by the surface area". Analogously § A.6.2 says "The noun “density” or the adjective “volumic” is added to the name of a quantity to indicate the quotient of that quantity by the volume". I just wanted to be consistent with the terminology I'm adopting.

Comment: ...for instance "heat flow" is measured in J/s, but "heat flow density" in J/(m² s). Similarly "magnetic flux" is in Wb, but  "magnetic flux density" (B) is in Wb/m².

Comment: The missing word is the quantity you're dealing with, $\dfrac{d}{dt} \text{quantity} + \text{flux [of the same quantity]} = \text{source [of the same quantity]}$.
**For sure, density is wrong**. You're dealing with the integral quantity, not a local one (and density is a local quantity): as an example, with mass $M_v = \int_v \rho$, and the integral balance reads
$\dfrac{d}{dt} \text{mass in $V$} + \text{flux of mass through $\partial V$} = \text{source of mass in volume $V$}$.

Answer (score 1):

The missing word is the **"quantity"** or **"integral quantity"** or **"extensive quantity"**, or **"physical quantity"** in physics, you're dealing with,
$$\dfrac{d}{dt} \text{quantity} + \text{flux [of the same quantity]} = \text{source [of the same quantity]} \ .$$

The word "quantity" stresses that you're dealing with an **integral variable** (intergral ~ sum): since you're summing, the result of this operation is an amount or a quantity.

As an example, with mass $M_V = \int_V \rho$ with continous mass distribution, or $M_V = \sum_{k \in V} M_k$ for discrete masses, the integral balance reads
$$\dfrac{d}{dt} \text{mass in $V$} + \text{flux of mass through $\partial V$} = \text{source of mass in volume $V$} \ .$$

In such a case, where the source is zero (restricting the discussion to classical mechanics), you could use the form **"conserved quantity"**, since the equation is the mathematical formulation of a conservation law.

Comment: It's too ambiguous and a little inconsistent. Flux is also "the amount of *quantity* that...", as you write in your equation. If we take "quantity" to mean a 3D integral, then that would mean "flux is the amount of the 3D integral..." etc, which is inconsistent. Also, from a mathematical point of view, the word we're looking for denotes a function that maps a 3D region and a time to a scalar (or vector, if we're speaking about momentum, say). That's not the meaning of "quantity", which is more generic.

Of course it's a great deal subjective! I appreciate the proposal :)

Comment: use **integral quantity** or **extensive quantity** then

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of using something similar, like *the total* or *the integral* of the quantity.